RankNTypes, Daisy Chaining
I've been working my way through understanding RankN types (where n==2 for the most part).  I have a situation where I have a function thusly:
z :: a -> [(forall q r .((q->r),(r->r)))] -> b

where I'd like a definition like:
z a fgs@((f,g):fgs') = -- for each (f,g) pair in fgs, feed a into f, then into g one or more times, and then feed forward the result into the next element of fgs, and finally produce the result b.

Obviously conceptually, this means that the last r of the last fg pair is b, and the first q of the first fg pair is a, and everything else along the way daisy-chains.
I keep running up against unification problems between the tail end r in q->r, and the first r in r->r (I think).
Removing, for simplicity, having a whole list of these things doesn't resolve the problem, however.  So, reducing the problem to:
z :: a -> (forall q r .((q->r),(r->r))) -> b

the logical implementation would be
z a (f,g) = g.f $ a

possibly with more applications of g.
It compiles well enough, but in an attempt to provide it with something like:
z "Hello World" ((\x -> length x), (\x -> x+1))

...the error I get is:
<interactive>:238:25: error: [GHC-25897]
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘r’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall q r. (q -> r, r -> r)
        at <interactive>:238:17-47
    • In the expression: length x
      In the expression: \ x -> length x
      In the second argument of ‘z’, namely
        ‘((\ x -> length x), (\ x -> x + 1))’

This problem goes away if I remove the forall, and do the substitution of q with a, and b with r, respectively, which would result in:
ghci> z "Hello World" ((\x -> length x), (\x -> x+1))
12

ghc version 9.6.5, ImpredicativeTypes is enabled (for the sake of the original list case at the top) which I believe implies RankNTypes.
Docs say that ImpredicativeTypes causes some problems for GHC's type checker, but I can't help but feeling I'm misunderstanding something about the individual steps the compiler's taking to try to make the types line up for the test input I just provided.
How is the compiler viewing this?  Why does it fail?  Is there a sensible way to do this that is even remotely close to what I attempted?

The type signature of z means that you have to pass it a pair of functions that work for all possible types q and r (that's literally what forall means), but the functions you're trying to pass clearly don't work for all possible types. The first function \x -> length x requires that q be a list (because you're calling length on it) and the second function \x -> x+1 requires that r has an instance of Num (because you're calling (+) on it).

If you want to daisy chain types like that, you have to use recursive type classes.

Yes, I think I got my understanding of this exactly backwards.  I told z to accept polymorphic functions, and then passed in regular functions expecting unification of the types.  By providing two ordinary functions where the types are defined, its the caller that has to unify those types -- but of course, I've got the function types hidden behind a forall, where they can't be.
I don't know how to do this unification the right way around (yet), but at least I see where I fumbled the ball, I think.


Why does it fail?

Well, (\x -> length x), (\x -> x+1) does not have type forall q r. (q -> r, r -> r) since the caller cannot pick q or r. Are you looking for existential types?
It's not too hard to come up with a GADT Daisy a b that chains a bunch of functions like you want. This is a form of existential type.
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Daisy a b where
    Nil :: Daisy a a
    Cons :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b) -> Daisy b c -> Daisy a c

run :: Daisy a b -> a -> b
run Nil = id
run (Cons f g d) = run d . g . f

test :: Daisy String Int
test = Cons length succ Nil

main = print $ run test "Hello World"
-- 12


"Are you looking for existential types?"
I think that was my intent -- to require passing polymorphic functions into z, to make z choose the types of those parameters.  But clearly I'm missing understanding RankNTypes and forall here.

But of course, I'm not passing polymorphic functions in.  I'm passing ordinary functions in, and attempting to get Haskell to unify the other direction.  I've got this exactly backwards.  I think I see that now.

There are no (non bottom) values of type forall q r .((q->r),(r->r)). Roughly, these non-existing values would be pairs (f,g) where
f :: forall q r. q -> r
g :: forall r  . r -> r

There is only one g having that polymorphic type: the identity function. Worse, there is no f having that polymorphic type, since it would be a function accepting any input type and producing any output type.
Your f = (\x -> length x) only accepts lists and only produces integers, so it's not general enough. Indeed, no definition can produce a function which is general enough -- the type simply promises too much.

This is one of those situations where I should at least have recognized that
g :: forall r  . r -> r
could only be the identity function.  From which I could possibly have deduced what you're saying if I were more practiced at this.  Nice.

Also, mad props for providing an avenue to a working solution, which is now making me try to understand GADTs, which I've also been meaning to do.  On this one problem, I've been learning more than I've had to in years. :)
